# Why am I getting this error about the compareTo method?

Tags: java, interface, compareto

I am trying to understand the `compareTo` method. I wrote this class `AboutcompareTo`, but i am stuck in why/how i get this error?- the code is nearly finished.
anyone can explain in details what i am doing wrong. Thanks

the code:

```
public class AboutCompareTo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit[] fruits = { new Fruit(2), new Fruit(3), new Fruit(1) };
        java.util.Arrays.sort(fruits);
    }

}

class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
    private double weight;

    public Fruit(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Fruit o) {
        Fruit f = (Fruit) o;
        if (Fruit > o.Fruit)  // <-- the error
            return 1;
        else if ((Fruit < o.Fruit))  // <-- the error
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: "_how i get this error?_" What error? Don't say you get an error without at least telling us what it is. And what exactly is `Fruit > o.Fruit` supposed to do?

Comment: You can't use the `>` and `<` operators, and their modifiers, to compare Java objects. You must use the objects methods itself to compare objects. `f.compareTo(o)`. Further, you need to define what it means for a Fruit to be bigger or smaller than another fruit. So change your compareTo() method to something like `return this.getWeight() - o.getWeight()`

Comment: You can not do relational operator to objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `compareTo` method compares an instance of your class, i.e. this `Fruit`, to an instance of another `Fruit` passed to you as a parameter. Therefore, the comparison needs to be between `o`'s *weight*, and your own weight:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Fruit o) {
    if (this.weight > o.weight)
        return 1;
    else if (this.weight < o.weight)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Note 1: I used `this.weight` to refer to the weight of this `Fruit`. I did this to point out that `weight` attribute belongs to this instance; however, you can omit `this.` from the expression, i.e. use `weight > o.weight` instead.

Note 2: I assume that you did this for a learning exercise. For production code Java class library provides a pre-built method for comparing `double`s - i.e. `Double.compare`. You can rewrite the method in a single line:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Fruit o) {
    return Double.compare(weight, o.weight);
}
```

Comment: Java 7 also has `Long.compare(a, b)` as does Integer.

Comment: You're right that it was an excercise that i would extend it a little bit to understand both the compareTo method and thinking in object. Thanks!

Comment: but the code does still not compile?- the intention was to use the sort method too.-